# MsBuild condition for new ("sdk-style") vs. old project format

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I want to write an msbuild "include" (.props) file that is to be imported in both the new ("sdk-style") projects as well as the old ones.

Is there a way to find out into which type of project the .props file is imported so I could use that in a condition? For example,

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ProjectType)'=='sdk'">
   <SomeProperty>SomeValue</SomeProperty>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I encountered this same need in my project.  At first I went with the solution @wexman, but I found that variable not to be reliable.  I considered the approach of opening the csproj file and using regexes to look for the SDK attribute, but it felt too brittle to me - especially given that the SDK can be specified either in an element or an attribute.  Finally I created a build with binary logging turned on (option `/bl`) and went hunting through the various files that get imported when doing a build of an SDK-style project.

I discovered the property `UsingMicrosoftNETSdk` which is set to `true` in the props file which auto-imports `Microsoft.Common.props` when you are using an SDK-style project.  This auto-import (which leads to the auto-import of Directory.Build.props seems to be one of the most important defining characteristics of SDK-style projects, and the name of the property makes it look like something more likely to stick around.

So in the end my solution was to have:

```
Condition="'$(UsingMicrosoftNETSdk)' == 'true'"
```

(or its inverse) as the reliable way to determine which type of project is in use.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that property. That's indeed a better solution, so marking this as an answer!

Answer (score 3):

I seem to have found a working solution. I'm checking against the property $(_PlatformWithoutConfigurationInference) declared in Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Props. If it is not empty, I'll be dealing with an sdk style project, if it is empty, it's a legacy project:

```
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectStyle Condition="'$(_PlatformWithoutConfigurationInference)'!=''">sdk</ProjectStyle>
    <ProjectStyle Condition="'$(_PlatformWithoutConfigurationInference)'==''">legacy</ProjectStyle>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="$(MsBuildProjectName) is a $(ProjectStyle) style project" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: Weirdly, when I tried this `<ProjectStyle Condition="'$(_PlatformWithoutConfigurationInference)'==''">legacy</ProjectStyle>` didn't seem to work as `ProjectStyle` is empty when `Message` is called. But testing `_PlatformWithoutConfigurationInference` works as a way of enabling parts of the props file depending on whether it's an sdk project or not, so +1 and thanks from me.

Comment: And then having written this, I see there's a simpler answer below. Still +1 from me, but I'll switch to that other solution :)

Answer (score 1):

While testing for property values (or the lack thereof) is how almost everything gets done in MSBuild, sometimes there are other ways.

**How do you know whether the current MSBuild project is a SDK project?**

In other words:

- given an XML file...
- whose full path is in the `MSBuildProjectFullPath` [well-known property](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties)...
- and whose first tag is `Project`...
- does said tag have a `Sdk` attribute?

Thanks to MSBuild's [property functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions), you can do the following:

- use `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText` to read the project file's contents as a string;
- then use `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch` to test for a `Project` tag with a `Sdk` attribute.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <_ProjectContents>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(`$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)`))</_ProjectContents>
  <_SdkRegex>(?s-i)(^|\s|&gt;)&lt;Project\s(([^&gt;]*?)\s)?Sdk(\s*?)=(\s*?)"</_SdkRegex>
  <_IsSdkProject>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch(`$(_ProjectContents)`, `$(_SdkRegex)`))</_IsSdkProject>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or, if you prefer a one-liner:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <_IsSdkProject>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::IsMatch(`$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(`$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)`))`, `(?s-i)(^|\s|&gt;)&lt;Project\s(([^&gt;]*?)\s)?Sdk(\s*?)=(\s*?)"`))</_IsSdkProject>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then you can use the value of `_IsSdkProject`, which will be either `True` OR `False`, in a `Condition`, like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(_IsSdkProject)'=='True'">
  <SomeProperty>SomeValue</SomeProperty>
</PropertyGroup>
```

---

**The regular expression explained**

In the above regular expression, the `<` and `>` characters have been replaced with XML entities (`&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively). The original regex is as follows:

```
(?s-i)(^|\s|>)<Project\s(([^>]*?)\s)?Sdk(\s*?)=(\s*?)"
```

Which means:

- In [single-line, case-sensitive mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options)...
- Either at the start of the file, or following a white-space character, or following a `>` character...
- find the literal string `<Project`...
- then a white-space character...
- then, optionally, any number of any character except `>`, and another white-space character...
- then the literal string `Sdk`...
- then, optionally, any number of white-space characters...
- then the character `=`...
- then, optionally, any number of white-space characters...
- then the character `"`

A better explanation, together with an online tester where you can insert your project files' contents and test in real time, is [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pFP2Dq/3). The site was made for Javascript regular expressions, which do not behave *exactly* like in .NET, but it is useful anyway.

Comment: This is not a good approach, because you shouldn't care whether imports were performed via Sdk import or regular import. In addition, there are other ways to reference the sdk: `<Import Sdk=` and `<Project><Sdk`.

Comment: @RainerSigwald true, there are other ways to reference the SDK, but the OP was most probably looking for something to use on their own projects, so it would be easy to enforce a convention to only use `Project Sdk=...`.

Comment: @RainerSigwald As for the usefulness of SDK-style project detection: you're absolutely right, _in theory_. In practice, though, it can be leveraged in interesting ways, especially if you have some common MSBuild code that gets imported in every project _and_ you're still stuck with (sigh!) WinForms, hence old-style projects, for applications, while using .NET Standard as much as possible for libraries.

Answer (score -2):

> MsBuild condition for new (“sdk-style”) vs. old project format

There is no directly solution for this question. Because there is no such property `ProjectType` in MSBuild/Visual Studio.

I would like provide a workaround here, you can check if it works for you. As we know, in the old project format, There will usually be a file `AssemblyInfo.cs`, which is not exists on the new "sdk-style" project format. So we could use the `Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs')"` to find out into which type of project the `.props` file is imported:

The content of my test `.props` file:

```
 <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs')">
    <SomeProperty>SomeValue1</SomeProperty>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="!Exists('$(ProjectDir)\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs')">
    <SomeProperty>SomeValue2</SomeProperty>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Test" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="$(SomeProperty)"></Message>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work for me. I do have legacy projects without assemblyinfo.cs as well as sdk-style projects with assemblyinfo.cs (i'm still putting the assembly-level attributes like InternalsVisibleTo() there).